# Cannot install RAY

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ray, modin

Ray library from RISE lab (https://rise.cs.berkeley.edu/blog/pandas-on-ray/)

I am using Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit and running these scripts from Anaconda prompt.

I have tried both

```
pip install ray
```

and

```
pip3 install ray
```

with the same result

```
Collecting ray
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ray (from versions: 
)
No matching distribution found for ray
```

It would be great to find a workaround or troubleshooting this. Thanks

Comment: I checked ray documentation, they do not seem to mention windows anywhere, I start to wonder if it is compatible with windows.

Comment: indeed not compatible with windows. maybe there will be a ray distribution for windows soon

Comment: It should now support windows!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Ray does support Windows in experimental capacity now!

See Windows installation instructions here:

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows-support

---

<s>Ray does not support Windows:</s>

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/2683

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/631

They propose to use the **Windows subsystem for Linux** as the most efficient workaround:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Do you have some timing comparisons between ray on windows subsystem for linux and ray on a proper linux?

Comment: If you're looking for more detailed instructions for the Windows installation, you find them here: https://www.btelligent.com/en/blog/how-to-install-ray-under-windows/

Answer (score 10):

Ray for windows is now available...

https://pypi.org/project/ray/

https://docs.ray.io/en/master/installation.html

Answer (score 5):

If you are on python 3.11 (as of 7th of Feb '23) Ray is also not available, so you need to downgrade to python 3.10 for now

You can install python 3.10 parallel to 3.11 and use the following commands to create a 3.10 environment

```
python3.10 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip install ray
```

Comment: Is there any update on when a python 3.11 package will be available?